# How to use python to extract the keywords in JSON format data?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, csv

My code currently converts a CSV file into JSON formatting, it successfully displays the JSON format of the data. But I would like to know what should I add on to extract the keywords like "Comedy", "Foreign", "Drama" as well as the "id"

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'xxx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='unicode_escape', usecols = ["id","genres"])


result = df.to_json(orient='records')
parsed = json.loads(result)
df2 = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
print(df2)
```

which gives the following result:

```json
{
        "genres": "[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10769, 'name': 'Foreign'}]",
        "id": 61008
    },
    {
        "genres": "[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}]",
        "id": 429200
    },
    {
        "genres": "[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]",
        "id": 331110
    },
    {
        "genres": "[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}]",
        "id": 436882
    },
```

Sample data in CSV file:

```json
[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 80, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]
[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]
[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]
```

Comment: extract into what? what would you like the output to be? what data structure would you like to store it in?

Comment: also are you sure that csv file example you showed is correct? that's a list of dicts, not **comma separated** data

Comment: For example, first data Animation, Comedy, Family would be displayed. Stored in CSV file. Thank you

Comment: The CSV file I showed is a cell in the CSV file, one row represent one cell. So I felt difficult in extracting the keywords

Comment: you have stored list of dicts/jsons in a csv column....?

Comment: please type out the **exact output** you seek in your question, a few lines - representing a few rows of the csv should be ideal

Comment: Each line of your sample csv file looks like json data. Iterate over the file and feed each line to json.loads then extract the info from the resulting list of dicts.